# Exchange 440 Timeout error

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am trying to access an Exchange 2003 server using WebDAV, but I get a (440) Login Timeout error whenever I try to connect to the Exchange web client (https://server/exchange/mailbox/inbox)

Any ideas on what would cause this? If I browse to the URL, I can login manually but I am unable to get past the 440 error when accessing the page programatically.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open AD Users & Computers. Expand the Users OU, right-click on the IUSR_ account and select 'Reset password' Reset the password to anything you want (however, it can't be blank).

2) Open this User Account's properties and verify that the account is not locked out. Also, make sure that 'Password never expires' and 'User cannot change password' are selected.

3) Repeat steps 1 & 2 for the IWAM_ account. Close AD Users & Computers.

4) Open Internet Information Services (Start | Administrative Tools)

5) Expand | Web Sites

6) Right-click on 'Default Web Site' and select Properties.

7) Go to the 'Directory Security' tab and click the Edit button under 'Authentication & Access Control'

8) Enter the new password for the IUSR_ account and click OK.

9) Enter the password again to confirm and click OK.

10) Click OK.

11) Open a command prompt and enter: iisreset

12) At the command prompt, enter the following commands:

cd c:\inetpub\adminscripts

adsutil SET w3svc/WAMUserPass (Where = the password you entered for the IWAM_ account in AD Users & Computers)

c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe "c:\inetpub\adminscripts\synciwam.vbs" -v

iisreset

Once you have all of this done authentication should work no problems.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have access to the Exchange server. I'll see if I can get the tech support folks to review this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error 440 occurs because Forms Base Authentication is enabled. You can implement following steps to rectify the above mentioned error.

1. Open Exchange Server and Click Start.
2. Then Click All Programs and then click Microsoft Exchange and then
   Open System Manager.
3. Then expand Exchange, then expand server and then the server name.
   Then expand Protocols and finally expand HTTP.
4. Right Click Exchange virtual server and then click properties and disable Forms Based Authentication by unmarking the box.